# Convert DAX function (incl. ALLEXCEPT, AVERAGE) to PowerQuery's M

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I am new to PowerBI (but I know coding and SQL), so my question might be simple or answered elsewhere - I'm happy about any forward.

I'm supposed to calculate an average currency rate per month and currency pair, thus grouped and ordered by other columns. All this should happen in Power Query, but I don't know how to reflect this in M.

In DAX, I reached a usable (yet not perfect) formula:

```
RATE_AVG_MONTH = IF (
  (Source_Tab[SOURCE_SYSTEM] == "System_1"),
  CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Source_Tab[RATE_AVG_DAILY]),
            ALLEXCEPT(Source_Tab, Source_Tab[CURRENCY_A], Source_Tab[CURRENCY_B], Source_Tab[MONTH], Source_Tab[YEAR])
  ),
)
```

Here is still missing that the result should be "ORDERed BY Source_Tab[YEAR]".

How can this be expressed in M?

Comment: You *can* write calculations like this if you really want to; [`Table.Group`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/table-group) shows an example of grouping (with a sum), but it's quite different from DAX in this regard so there's quite a learning curve. It's also not exactly optimized to this sort of calculation like DAX is; it shines at filtering and transforming. If you don't want to use DAX on the client end, you're typically better off doing the calculations at the source (in SQL, for example) and leaving M to just import the data with minor transformations if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I don't want to do the calculations in DAX because there is a column that should be removed in the query transformation (s.t. it is not in the report), but it is true: better doing this in SQL before.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're taking the straight average of a daily rate that exists on Source_Tab.

To do this transformation in M (it's easier to use the GUI than the code):

On Source_Tab, select currency A, Currency B, Month, and Year by control-clicking the columns, and click on 'Group By'.

In 'New Column Name', name your column, change the operation to average, and select the rate field in column.

If you're doing something more complex, like attempting to derive an average rate from a set of transactions in a day, and then average that rate up to month, you'd simply do this operation twice, grouping once by day, and a second time by month and year.

I agree with the above comment that M isn't ideal for doing this. It absolutely CAN do this transformation, but there would likely be more efficient places to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As proposed by you and Jeroen, I'll try to not do this transformation in M. But put it more early, to the SQL of the source.